# Django Bi-directional ManyToMany - How to prevent table creation on second model?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two models, each has a shared ManyToMany, using the db_table field.  But how do I prevent syncdb from attempting to create the shared table, for the second model?

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    othermodels = ManyToManyField('Model2', db_table='model1_model2', related_name='model1_model2')

class Model2(models.model):
    othermodels = ManyToManyField('Model1', db_table='model1_model2', related_name='model2_model1')
```

It's working great in my dev environment, because some of the tables got created piecemeal, as I built it all out.  But from an empty database, syncdb throws:
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'model1_model2' already exists")

Is there a flag that I'm missing from the second model's field to prevent duplicate table creation?  Or am I just doing this entirely wrong?

Answer (score 28):

I also found this solution, which worked perfectly for me :

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    tests2 = models.ManyToManyField('Test2', blank=True)

class Test2(models.Model):
    tests1 = models.ManyToManyField('Test1', through=Test1.tests2.through, blank=True)
```

Comment: This is the best I have found. Works great, truly bidirectional.

Comment: Still seems to be the best solution- can't see any drawbacks, so i don't understand why it's not suggested in the docs

Comment: Related docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Wish I knew about this years ago!

Comment: Tested this, this solution create two datatable for me. app_test1_test2 and app_test2_test1. Using through with a custom model works, that seems strange.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to put a `ManyToManyField` on both sides of the relation. [Django will do that for you](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

You probably want something more like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    othermodels = models.ManyToManyField(Model1, through='Model1Model2')
    ...        

class Membership(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'model1_model2'
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)        
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
```

When you're working with your models, an instance of `Model1` will have a `othermodels_set` field which is automatically added by django. Instances of `Model2` will have `othermodels`.

Comment: Using a through statement to point to a third model that contains the relationship, seemed to make it difficult to present it in the Admin, on both models.  Especially without doing an Inline, which does not play nicely with FormSets.

Comment: The "through" model is optional, and it's table will be generated automatically if omitted. I only included it to set the name of the table to match your example. And yes, sometimes you have to do a little tweaking to make the admin nice with complex models.

Comment: Hrm.  I wonder if I could kludge it by building the intermediary table class, setting that as Abstract, and then only using through on the second call.

Comment: Seems like `through='Model1Model2'` should (or could) have been `through='Membership'`.

Comment: here model1 instance will have `model2_set`. and model2 will have `othermodels`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Awesome(models.Model):
 one = models.TextField()
 class Meta:
  # Prevent table creation. 
  abstract = True
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

It's not what you're looking for, but it's the closest they have I belive. Would it not be simpler to make a view?

Maybe:

```
class Awesome(models.Model):
  one = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  two = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class AwesomeOne(Awesome):
  fieldOne = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'one')
  class Meta:
   abstract = True
class AwesomeTwo(Awesome):
  fieldTwo = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'two')
  class Meta:
   abstract = True
```

Then, you can have one table created and override the `__getattr__` to block access to the original fields.

Comment: It might be simpler to make a view, but so far I've gotten by in this project with just Admin forms.  It'd be quite a large amount of work to migrate everything to custom views, at this point.  Quite a lot more than running syncdb, deleting a table, and rerunning syncdb.

Comment: Perhaps what I need is an abstract option on ManyToMany fields.

Comment: As long as you set the database tables to the same name and prevent the second model from creating the table you should be all right. However I've never seen this before and frankly I don't think it's a good idea. (Which, it might be to late to change now. ) Because the models in models.py are meant to have a table; you could also move the model into another .py class. In the end, your desired result is to stop creation of the second table. This does the job, but it's a hack at the api no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

In Django ManyToMany are bi-directional by default. The think is that you only have to define it on one model, not on both (and usually you don't need to give a name to the table):

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    othermodels = ManyToManyField('Model2')

class Model2(models.model):
    ...
```

That's it. Now `syncdb` will be happy. For more info: [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

The only drawback is, if you use the admin, you will have access to `othermodels` only in `Model1`.

### Edit

So, if you want to have access to the ManyToMany in both models in the Admin, currently the *official* solution is to use [inlinemodel](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for the second model. I had also this same problem/need just a few days ago. And I was not really satisfied with the *inlinemodel* solution (heavy in DB queries if you have a lot of entries, cannot use the *filter_horizontal* widget, etc.).

The solution I found (that's working with Django 1.2+ and `syncdb`) is this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    othermodels = models.ManyToManyField('Model2', through='Model1Model2')

class Model2(models.Model):
    othermodels = models.ManyToManyField('Model1', through='Model1Model2')

class Model1Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_model1_model2'
        auto_created = Model1
```

See ticket [897](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897) for more info.

Unfortunately, if you're using [South](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsouth.aeracode.org%2F&ei=hclKTYrJCIH-8AbC9bDrDg&usg=AFQjCNHLHvNRc-6D5VPx8xePP0nnkDvYDw&sig2=62dGIQokom5XlHXtCK0vWA) you will have to remove the creation of the `app_model1_model2` table in every migration file created automatically.

Comment: That's exactly the issue.  I have to have the ManyToMany in both models, in the Admin.

Comment: Your edit shows promise.  I'll attempt implementing that, once I have a breather from my current rush of work.