# django model for list of objects' relations to each other?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I have a social-clique-object.

In each social-clique-object I have a list of friend-objects.

Each friend-object has a relationship-object (full of fun facts like when they met) *with each other friend.*

Herein I am stuck.  How do I properly define my models so that I can query any friend-object to pull up their shared relationship-object?

I do not see this is simply solved with a [bidirectional model like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881578/django-bi-directional-manytomany-how-to-prevent-table-creation-on-second-model) since I am dealing with a large and growing list of friend objects (in the linked-to solution they create two different models e.g. friend_a and friend_b).

My current approach was for the Relationship object to look like what is posted below. I would have to add logic in my code to prevent duplicate Relationship objects...  but this

```
 class Relationship(models.Model):
     social_clique = models.ForeignKey( Social_Clique )
     friend_0 = models.ManyToManyField( Friend, related_name='friend_0' )
     friend_1 = models.ManyToManyField( Friend, related_name='friend_1' )
```

I sense I am missing the right keyword to google for to find the ORM design pattern for this problem.  Any suggestions on the right description of this problem or how to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for either of the `friend_x` fields to be ManyToManys. The relationship between friends is ManyToMany, but `Relationship` is itself the intermediary model in the many-to-many relationship (hence the name). So the friend_ fields should be ForeignKeys, and then you additionally define a ManyToMany field from Friend to itself using Relationship as the `through` model:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    social_clique = models.ForeignKey(Social_Clique)
    friend_0 = models.ForeignKey(Friend, related_name='friend_0')
    friend_1 = models.ForeignKey(Friend, related_name='friend_1')

class Friend(models.Model):
    ... other fields ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Friend', through=Relationship)
```

Now it's easy to go from two friends (`me` and `my_friend`) to their shared relationship:

```
Relationship.objects.get(friend_0=me, friend_1=my_friend)
```

or

```
me.friend_0.filter(friend1=my_friend)
```

etc. And you can still get all my friends:

```
me.friends.all()
```

Comment: In `Relationship.objects.get(friend_0=me, friend_1=my_friend)` the ordering of the args suggests I have to get the order right to the Relationship. How would I know which order to put the args for getting the one relationship btwn arbitrary friend_x and friend_y?  Pick a strategy like alphabetizing on names of the friends? ...

Comment: Good question. The issue is that recursive many-to-many relations with a through table [can't be symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). You might solve this by automatically creating *two* `Relationship` instances when setting up a friendship, one for each direction.

Comment: Ya, except it is a shared relationship  -- just one between a pair.  I think I will use orderable keys (alpha or dates) from the Friends to always get the right relationship back and to create the right relationship.